# Laravel resource with parameter causing other routes to throw error

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am running into this issue where if I define a param in that first route, the second throws this error:

"Route pattern "/browse/{brand}/{{brand}}" cannot reference variable name "brand" more than once."

```
Route::resource('browse/{brand}', 'BrowseController');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'service'), function() { 
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticationController');
});
```

If I take out the param, of course that breaks the browse route, but then the auth route works.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because `Route::resource` creates several (RESTful) route handlers for you in the background for the controller you specify:

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Take a look at the table called: **Actions Handled By Resource Controller**

You can see that Laravel will already handle routes for you that take parameter that you can use to implement browsing.

I don't think that the intended usage for `Route::resource` is to be parametrized like you are trying to.

Of course you can always implement additional routes if those do not match your needs.

Comment: That table does show a a method that allows you to pass in a parameter, Show. The odd thing is if I reverse the order of the routes, they both work and I don't get the error, but anything after that fails. Unclear on what is going on. I was able to solve the issue by registering a GET route instead and adding another method to the controller 
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'service'), function() { 
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticationController');
});

Route::resource('browse/{brand}', 'BrowseController');

Comment: example:

you have a Client model and a Property model, would this just make sense

clients/1/properties/create
clients/1/properties/store
clients/1/properties/show/2

‍♂️